# Where to set User Properties in iOS for Firebase Analytics?

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have several user types:
Type A, Type B, Type C
User has to chose its type at time of sign up and it gets fixed for a particular user.
A user cannot change its type. How can I set User property so that a particular event can be filters using User Type? 
Suppose event is logged by name : example_event
I want to check that how many users of type A triggers example_event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **UserProperty** tab in `Firebase` console of your project. Click **NEW USER PROPERTY**.
Enter a name and description for the user property, then click CREATE.

Let's suppose you have set **USER_TYPE** as `Firebase` property .

Now  you can fire this property using below code .

```
Analytics.setUserProperty(USER_TYPE, forName: "A/B/C")
```

It will take some time to reflect on your `Events` tab of your `Firebase` project console.

Comment: At what time should it be fired?

Comment: when you get to know which type of user is this .